# Estimate the charge supplied by the input pulse in the following circuits. What is each circuits' input capacitance?

Tags: transistors, cmos, homework

[image]
Source: CMOS Circuit Design, Layout, and Simulation, Fourth Edition by R. Jacob Baker. 201

I am having trouble solving for this one.
I think I did the difference in voltage between gate and drain and try to find the charge that way but I am not sure if I am doing this right.

So what I did was I did for NMOS is: Q = C*V so Q = 1pF*{5V-(5v)} = 10pC.
The SPICE simulation was a bit different: 18.72pC(with 1k res).
and I assumed the same for the PMOS but the SPICE simulation for it was 4.71pC(with 1k res)

So what other information do I need to solve this?

Additionally, if I repeat the two problems with 1pF capacitor reconnected between the source and gate, what would be different?
The simulations were:
NMOS: 20.10pC
PMOS: 9.61pC

A little help would be appreciated.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson  CMOS Circuit Design, Layout, and Simulation, Fourth Edition by R. Jacob Baker. 2019. Free access from his website: http://cmosedu.com/jbaker/courses/ecg721/f21/ecg721_f21.zip.

Comment: Why are you assuming that the voltage on the gate changes by 10V? I don't see any such information in the question. What have you estimated for the gate capacitance of the MOSFET itself?

Comment: Also, I would suggest you ask Prof. Baker for assistance. I have always found him to be approachable.

Comment: This may not help, but it simulates a FET with no input capacitance but Beta is 10m from which you can link to rdson https://tinyurl.com/yfao9bch

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I got some comments from the graded homework and I will see if those will answer my question!

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 That is an awesome website. Thank you for introducing me to it.

Comment: yes and it can run offline with source files or any mobile. Some learning curve on all the features and ideal characteristics demand you add non-ideal passives to use this universal feature rather than device specific. Diodes can be defined with a dozen parameters